# Download data file 5-40 MB in android 2.2 from URL. Which classes to use for development?

Tags: android, streaming, download, android-2.2-froyo, progressive-download

I am developing an application in which i need to download a file(.zip / .txt / .jpg etc) size- 5 to 50 MB.. Application based on Android 2.2.

The user provides the **URL** and triggers the download but then the downloading process runs in background until complete.

**streaming** should be used for downloading file.
I want to know how can this be done using **HTTP connections**.
what **classes** can be used for this?
Does android 2.2 provides an API for this?

Any kind of help is appreciated....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android did include an API called `DownloadManager` for just this purpose...but it was release in 2.3; so while it won't be useful in your application targeting 2.2, it might still be a good resource for you to research the implementation.

A simple implementation I would recommend is something like this:

- Use an `HttpURLConnection` to connect and download the data. This will require the INTERNET permission to be declared in your manifest
- Determine where you want the file to be.  If you want it on the device's SD card, you will also need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
- Wrap this operation in the doInBackground() method of an `AsyncTask`.  This is a long-running operation, so you need to put it into a background thread, which AsyncTask manages for you.
- Implement this in a `Service` so the operation can run protected without the user keeping the an Activity in the foreground.
- Use `NotificationManager` to notify the user when the download is complete, which will post a message to their status bar.

To simplify things further, if you use `IntentService`, it will handle the threading for you (everything in `onHandleIntent` gets called on a background thread) and you can queue up multiple downloads for it to handle one at a time by simply sending multiple Intents to it.  Here's a skeleton example of what I'm saying:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

public static final String EXTRA_URL = "extra_url";
public static final int NOTE_ID = 100;

public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(!intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_URL)) {
        //This Intent doesn't have anything for us
        return;
    }
    String url = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        //Input stream from the connection
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        //Output stream to a file in your application's private space
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("filename", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Read and write the stream data here

        result = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Post a notification once complete
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification note;
    if(result) {
        note = new Notification(0, "Download Complete", System.currentTimeMillis());
    } else {
        note = new Notification(0, "Download Failed", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    manager.notify(NOTE_ID, note);

}
}
```

Then you can call this service with the URL you want to download anywhere in an Activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
intent.putExtra(DownloadService.EXTRA_URL,"http://your.url.here");
startService(intent);
```

Hope that is helpful!

**EDIT:** I'm fixing this example to remove the unnecessary double-threading for anyone who comes upon this later.

Comment: design
Actually i can do it on **android 2.3.** now, changed the scope.
So can u please explain me how to use the DownloadManager class for the same purpose please..
actually i cant find anything about it.. thanx a lot in advance...

Comment: Mark Murphy (@commonsguy) has probably the best and easiest to follow sample I'm aware of using DownloadManager...it's a pretty straightforward API...http://goo.gl/lVtzO.  And here's the Developer Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: I appreciate the complement.  If you feel that way, hows about accepting the answer? Cheers.